# Teamcity and gitosis authentication issue

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, gitosis

I've a git repository administered by gitosis on my server. On the same server I have teamcity for my CI.

I can't seem to connect to the git repository through teamcity.

I've an Administrator user that can access the repository (its under a git user on the same server) through cygwin, however when I try to setup teamcity to access with the Administrator's private key I get an authentication issue: 'Connection test failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail'.

In team city I have username style as email, authentication method as private key, the username is the same as the public key and the path to the private key is correct.

When using password access I'm told the path doesn't look like a git repository, even though it is and works fine through cygwin.

If anyone has teamcity connecting to a gitosis repository please let me know how you managed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.... I was using the wrong user type. I was using just user name not user name email.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem.  IT would really add value if you could post an example of what it was and what it is now that it works.